# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{5 + \sqrt{x^2+5}}{x-6}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't know how to evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{5 + \sqrt{x^2+5}}{x-6}$$

1. It is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$
2. I have tried to multiply by $5 - \sqrt{x^2+5}$, but I reach a wrong result.
3. I have tried to take the derivative of $5 + \sqrt{x^2+5}$ and $x-6$, but this also doesn't help.

Probably, I should use another method. Which method do I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{5+\sqrt{x^2+5}}{x-6}=\frac{\frac{5}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{5}{x^2}}}{\frac{x}{x}-\frac{6}{x}}=\frac{\frac{5}{x}+\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}{1-\frac{6}{x}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{x}+\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}{1-\frac{6}{x}}=\frac{0+\sqrt{1+0}}{1-0}=1$$

Comment: It's worth noting that the first equality does not hold for $x$ in general, but only because we implicitly assume that $x$ is positive.

Comment: @AMPerrine My answer assumes that by $x\to\infty$ OP meant $x\to +\infty $. We have $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{5+\sqrt{x^2+5}}{x-6}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{x}-\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}{1-\frac{6}{x}}=\frac{0-\sqrt{1+0}}{1-0}=-1$ so that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{5+\sqrt{x^2+5}}{x-6}$ doesn't exist. My textbook, however, uses $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ to denote $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}$. And of course when calculating $\lim_{x\to +\infty}$ I assume that $x>0$ and when calculating $\lim_{x\to -\infty}$ I assume that $x<0$.

Comment: @AMPerrine After $x$ reaches $0$ and starts getting closer to $+\infty$, the value of the function will start getting arbitrarily close to the limit I'm calculating. The point is to prove that after some point the value of the function will start getting arbitrarily close, and that point can be $0$.

Comment: Sure, my point was that since you write the first line as an equality not involving limits, readers should realize that it only holds for certain values of $x$. In my experience, many (most?) students would get the same result if $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Derivative of the numerator: $(5+ \sqrt{x^2+5})'= (\sqrt{x^2+5})'= \frac{(x^2+5)'}{2}\sqrt{x^2+5}^{-1} = \frac{2x}{2 \sqrt{x^2+5}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}$.

Derivative of the denominator: $(x-6)'=1$.

L'Hospital's rule is possible.